# ClosedXML - Style Rows and Columns in C#

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I'm working on a ASP.net Excel project, and I'm trying to add some different color (red) to an specific cell (M2,N2,O2,P2,Q2).

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    sda.Fill(dt);
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Excel.xlsx");
        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
}
```

I'm trying to add some rows after `wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");` but i cant find the way.

I'm trying to implement this:

```
dt.Rows(13, 14, 15, 16, 17).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;
```

Comment: You can look at this repository. It really helps with exporting data to excel. 
https://github.com/TopSoftSolutions/TopSoft.ExcelExport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways for this:

```
dt.Rows(13, 17)... // first and last row as number

dt.Rows("13, 14, 15, 16, 17").... // string with row numbers like in Excel itself
```

For specific cells you can use similar calls (M2 ... Q2 like in the question):

```
dt.Range(2, 14, 2, 18)... // row and column numbers for a rectangular area of cells

dt.Range("M2:Q2")... // string like in Excel
```